# How to transfer login token to a downloaded desktop application

Tags: web, windows-installer, desktop-application

I have a website that has a login page. After the login it generates a token for each user (using a cookie).

At some point, after login, the user decides to download my desktop application.

I would like the user to seamlessly login in the desktop application (meaning, I would like the web token to transfer somehow to the downloaded desktop application).

I thought about two options that eventually came up empty:

1. custom links like http://mywebsite/installer.msi?token=abc. **Problem**: but I couldn't figure out a way for the MSI to know what was the origin URL it was downloaded from (how do I get that abc string?)
2. Using uri schema to invoke the installed app from the webpage with the token. **Problem**: I don't know when the installation was completed. Plus, it involves a user interaction which is something I would like to avoid

My last resort is embedding the token inside the MSI file dynamically for each user (without corrupting it somehow) and reading it inside the installer. But it doesn't seem like a good way to achieve this.

I hope there is another proper way to do it.

Thanks,

Lidan

Comment: How do you know that user that has the token and the user running the desktop application are the same?

Comment: That's the problem. I made two attempts for that (above) and it doesn't seem to fit my needs. I'm not sure if embedding the token inside the MSI is the only way to go. There may be something I'm missing here, another API or file header or something that allows me to transfer this parameter

Comment: Well, my point is that you _cannot_ know. You need to re-authenticate the user. If one can just transfer a token any user can grab the token of someone else and just pass it to the other program.

Comment: But I can provide a wrapper URL for the download that would add a file property dynamically. The file property would contain the token. Is there any other way?

Comment: What exactly does "log in to the web site" mean? If it means some kind of ASP login that is valid on the current Windows system then you could do the download an initiate the install from the ASP process that is effectively impersonating with the supplied credentials.